# unable to retrieve files from u1 fie system

Tags: 14.04

just been reminded too recover my files from the u1 cloud service. when i follow all instructions given on the installation faqs i get this line

bash: ./u1_downloader: cannot execute binary files: Exec format error

can some one please help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're trying to run the 64-bit version on a 32-bit computer. Try downloading http://ubuntuone.com/u1-downloader/u1-downloader-32b.tar.gz.